# Visualising a Raster (KAP open sea map file) using python with rasterio how do I get the colours correct

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, colormap, openseamap

I have just started using rasterio to show raster maps in Python. I want to display some OpenSeaMap (KAP raster format). I have started with a single kap file, I can load and display a single kap file. However, the colours are not what I want. My code is below.
`

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
src = rasterio.open("L10-296-560-8-24_10.kap",cmap='')   
show(src)
```

`
This displays

[image]

But what I want is

[image]

Does anyone know how I tweek the colormap to get to what I want? Or maybe I should be using a different python library.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured one solution. I simply exported the kap file to a GeoTiff using QGIS.

```
import rasterio
src = rasterio.open("kap5.tif")
from rasterio.plot import show
show(src)
```

Then I get this.

[image: Nice right coloured map :-)]